# Any way to install nvidia gpu driver 390 on ubuntu18 google cloud

Tags: cuda, gpu, google-compute-engine, nvidia

After installed cuda9.2 by run file, tried to run nvidia-smi, but it said no connection to nvidia gpu driver. Tried several ways to install nvidia gpu driver 390, all not successful.

Also tried using start script to create instance with cuda9.0, but cuda not installed. Manual install cuda9.0 also failed.

They said that GCP can only support gpu driver up to 384. Is the version  updated? What is the best way to install nvidia driver and cuda. Which latest cuda version is supported? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/) in the GCP documentation, the latest version supported is “NVIDIA 384.111 driver or greater” in Linux instances.

Your questions are answered in [this article.](https://medium.com/@aidemocratization/deep-learning-with-google-cloud-platform-part2-how-to-install-cuda-on-your-compute-engine-2665d728e532) The article has all the installation steps on how to install cuda and Nvidia drivers.